# Official source for MFPlat.dll

Tags: windows-7, dll

I have software that has been copied from computer to computer (these exact files) many times, no install required. On the latest computer it complains that MFPlat.dll is missing. What is MFPlat.dll actually? What is a safe source to download it, or failing that - what software should I install / reinstall to get it?

OS is Windows 7x64, computer make is Toshiba - I'll be extra happy if someone can tell me what Toshiba driver to download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFPlat is the Media Foundation Platform DLL from Windows Vista and Windows 7.  Its an integral part of the OS so no manufacturer download will fix this.

Don't download from these DLL Download sites that proliferate, you run the risk of spyware

There's a guide to fixing this correctly at http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/mfplat-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm

If you still have your Win7 installation media available, you may be able to locate the file on there, often within a .CAB file that you'd need to extract first

Answer (score 1):

This `dll` file is part of the Windows Media Player Pack.

Some installations of Windows do not come with Media Player "N" or "KN" versions

[Follow this link to install the media pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16546).